# Query regarding ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am executing a Statement query and storing the data in ResultSet rs.

```
// if no record is returned by the query

if (!rs.next() ) {
Step1
}

// if atleast one record is returned by the query

if(rs.next()){
do {

  if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
          Step2
  }

  if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
         Step3
 }
}              while (rs.next());
}
```

However if i am getting only a single record from the query then no steps are executed. It would be of great help if anyone can point out the mistake.

Comment: Note : `if(condition) do{ } while(condition);`, if the condition are exactly the same, this is the same as `while(condition){}` unless you use an `else` where you can add the `Step1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are always skipping first element because you are calling `.next()` twice before taking an element.
Try doing something like this:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    // At least one record returned
    do {
        if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
            // Step2
        }

        if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            // Step3
        }
    } while (rs.next());
} else {
    // No records returned
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to understand  what exactly  `next()`  method do.  next() moves the cursor to next element.  When you write `next()` inside if there the condition passed and there are no more elements when it comes to `while`.

And why don't you simplify your code by just doing

```
while ( rs.next() ) { 
   if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
          Step2
  }

  if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
         Step3
 }
}
```

If you enter into while loop, there are items, otherwise No.

Comment: `ResultSet` doesn't have `hasNext()` method

Comment: No, this is [`isLast()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isLast()) in the Resultset.

Answer (score 2):

From JavaDoc [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()):

> Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position. A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

In your code you don't need second invocation of `rs.next()` because cursor already on first row.

Answer (score 2):

Initially `rs` contains one record or more precisely points to result set having one record.

Now when `if(!rs.next())` is called then rs moves to the next record in result set which is not there as you have only one record. So this if goes well. But again when you use `if(rs.next())` then `rs` won't be having any record, hence the `if` won't execute.

Answer (score 2):

You should not call `rs.next()` method twice. Following logic should work:

```
    if (!rs.next() ) {
       Step1
    }
    else{ // if atleast one record is returned by the query

        do {
          if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                  Step2
          }
          if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                 Step3
         }
        }while (rs.next());
    }
```